# Symfony Dynamically Adding Entry to Form Leads to TypeError

Tags: forms, symfony

In my form, I have a collection of forms embedded. The idea is to use jQuery to add or remove an entry (from the collection). The jQuery part works fine. I know for a fact that my entities are fine as well, because I used EasyAdminBundle before to realise this functionality and that was no problem.

The problem is: When I add an entry via jQuery and submit the form, I get the following error:

`Type error: Return value of App\Entity\Answer::getIsCorrect() must be of the type boolean, null returned`

This is the parent form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\Entity\Question;
use App\Form\DataTransformer\TagTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class QuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('answers', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => AnswerType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'delete_empty' => true,
                    'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                    'prototype' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                )
            )
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => Question::class
            )
        );
    }
}
```

This is the collection form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use App\Entity\Answer;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Choice;

class AnswerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'isCorrect',
                CheckboxType::class,
                ['required' => false]
            )
            ->add(
                'text',
                 TextType::class,
                ['label' => false, 'required' => false]
            );
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Answer::class
        ));
    }
}
```

Here are some facts:

- Symfony 3.3 used
- Entities work fine
- jQuery works fine
- Forms with fixtures can be submitted fine
- The whole setup is largely inspired by [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)

I read that there could be a problem when `allow_add` is not true. But that is explicitly set. Removing entries works fine. `delete_empty` is ignored as well.

My first thought was that there is a problem because the form fields are not duplicated correctly by jQuery, e.g. wrong name attribute used. Especially checkboxes can sometimes be problematic. But even if I only use a text field, the issue persists. As an example:

Generated with Twig:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="question_answers_2_isCorrect" name="question[answers][2][isCorrect]" value="1">
```

Result from jQuery:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="question_answers_3_isCorrect" name="question[answers][3][isCorrect]" value="1">
```

Now, here comes the kicker: In the Stack Trace, you can clearly see that the form has the data in the first place, but it gets lost.

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError:
Type error: Return value of App\Entity\Answer::getIsCorrect() must be of the type boolean, null returned

  at src/Entity/Answer.php:82
  at App\Entity\Answer->getIsCorrect()
     (vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyAccessor.php:487)
  at Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->readProperty(array(object(Answer)), 'isCorrect')
     (vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyAccessor.php:410)
  at Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->readPropertiesUntil(array(object(Answer)), object(PropertyPath), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyAccessor.php:179)
  at Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->getValue(object(Answer), object(PropertyPath))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php:92)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper->mapFormsToData(object(RecursiveIteratorIterator), object(Answer))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Form.php:630)

// Here the data is suddenly lost

  at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit(array(), true)
     (vendor/symfony/form/Form.php:574)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit(array(array('text' => 'this gets lost')), true)
     (vendor/symfony/form/Form.php:574)

// Here the data comes in, now see above ↑

at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit(array('answers' => array(array('isCorrect' => '1', 'text' => 'foo'), array('text' => 'bar'), array('text' => 'baz'), array('text' => 'this gets lost'))), true)
     (vendor/symfony/form/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php:113)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationRequestHandler->handleRequest(object(Form), object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/form/Form.php:500)
  at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->handleRequest(object(Request))
     (src/Controller/QuestionsController.php:79)
```

Here's the entity `Answer`:

```
class Answer
{
    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $text;

    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $isCorrect;

    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="answers", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $question;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getText() : string
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $text
     */
    public function setText(string $text) : void
    {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIsCorrect() : bool
    {
        return $this->isCorrect;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $isCorrect
     */
    public function setIsCorrect(bool $isCorrect) : void
    {
        $this->isCorrect = $isCorrect;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work is your checkbox isCorrect is checked ?
If yes, in your entity model of Answer, you should set the default value of isCorrect to false, I think.

Comment: It does not, even if it is checked.

Comment: Ok, are you using php 7 ? Can you share the model of your Entity Answer ?

Comment: Yes, PHP 7 is used. I added the entity. What I'd like to emphasize: Using DoctrineFixtures, I already added some Answers to the Question Entity and these are shown in the form. Each Answer has an entry in the form collection generated. I can alter the values in this entry, i.e. leave textboxes blank, uncheck checkboxes or remove the entry alltogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the culprit

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIsCorrect() : bool
{
    return $this->isCorrect;
}
```

Change it to

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getIsCorrect() : bool
{
    return boolval($this->isCorrect);
}
```

EDIT: ok I'll try to be a little more informative. Teh reason you're getting errors like these is because typehints in your methods are false. For instance your getIsCorrect method says it returns bool but in reality it also returns null when your isCorrect property isn't initialized. Personally I'd recommend  you remove the typehints for good and just keep phpdoc, but if you really need them then try initializing your fields in your entity's constructor and setting a default db value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the Exception is not appearing anymore, indeed. But the text field in the form has the same problem now.